# Can't upload iOS dSYM file to Flurry

Tags: flurry

I used to upload iOS dSYM files to Flurry by referring to the following site, but suddenly stopped working.
https://github.com/flurry/upload-clients

1.Download symbols from AppStoreConnect

2.Run the script using the -p  argument. eg.

```
./upload-symbols.py -c flurry.config -p ~/Downloads/dSYMs.zip
```

Then this was displayed on console.

```
16:26:35 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:85 fetching project
16:26:36 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:88 taring files
16:27:49 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:95 archive:/var/folders/fp/tmgnb44d03l5d0pg6m68zf1w0000gt/T/tmp36ZFXO.tgz (10804524 b)
16:27:49 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:97 creating upload
16:27:50 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:100 uploading file
16:29:01 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:335 Upload status: Waiting
16:29:07 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:335 Upload status: Waiting
16:29:12 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:335 Upload status: Waiting
16:29:18 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:335 Upload status: Waiting
16:29:24 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:335 Upload status: Waiting
16:29:29 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:335 Upload status: Waiting
16:29:35 [INFO] upload-symbols.py:335 Upload status: In Queue
Upload was not processed. If this issue persists please contact Flurry Support
Error: Internal Error: 1005
```

What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with uploading dsyms has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Still facing the same issue with Flurry SDK version 11.4.0. The issue doesn't always occur, but it sure repeats.

What I think is that the problem is with the flurry server as its successful response rate is nearly 86 percent. When it fails the server might be failing to respond during the build(script execution). Tried building on multiple devices and networks. The issue still persists.
If you find a solution that works and the reason why it does, It would be of great help.